# Copy element as ID for Pasting as Link in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have to add a reference from a table in a model and as I see you could do it like this:

[image]
and then in the model right click -> paste element as Link.

My EA version is 12.0.1215 and I don't have this copy/paste submenu.

[image: 12.0.1215]

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is it that you try to copy? Element, attribute, other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that you can drag an drop a table from project browser in a model giving the option to drop as link.